# 100 % black logo in scribus

Tags: color, print-design, black, scribus

I need to include EPS pictures (logos and barcode) in a Scribus project.

These pictures appear as CMYK(0,0,0,100) when opened with Inkscape, yet the printing company complains that it's not.

I believe the issue comes from Scribus : the properties window show a select box for the source profile, and for EPS pictures I have only 4 choices : *Compatible with Adobe RGB (1998)*, *Lstar-RGB.icc*, *ProPhoto-RGB* and *sRGB*.

I tried with and without black point compensation, but it seems to make no difference.

How do I force Scribus to render this pictures as 100 % black in the PDF output ?

Note that the output has to be CMYK and the document also contains color pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to import the EPS in the Scribus file (File > Get Vector File...), instead of loading it into an image frame.

Depending on the Scribus version and on the software / libraries installed Scribus can (or not) read EPS file.

Comment: The versions I use have issues with some files (both EPS and SVG, one has to convert them or recreate them differently), but it's ok for most of the files and it seems the colors are correct indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that unchecking the "*Embed PDF & EPS Files (EXPERIMENTAL)*" option in PDF export settings did the trick.  However with such a label I wonder how reliable it is…

The tooltip mentions it doesn't support color spaces *yet*, maybe this is my luck…

Anyway, hopefully someone will come up with a better option ?

Comment: Presumably, this *embeds* the data in the Scribus project file rather than *linking* it. Especially in light of the color spaces tooltip, it sounds like it must convert the object in some manner. IMO, it is best to defer such conversions to the pre-press people, unless you must e.g. export to PDF for submission.

Comment: Yes, that's the point : I must export to PDF for submission…

Comment: Linking is always preferred. Export the PDF instead, which ought to prevent conversion upon embedding. But I *think* the actual problem here is going to be either the CMYK values are being converted and embedded as RGB and RGB(0,0,0) is not always going to re-convert  to CMYK(0,0,0,100%) **or** the RGB is then exported as "rich black."

Comment: As far as I know, the missing part in the PDF/EPS embedding is that the color management is not applied to those parts.

Comment: And the reason why it works for you, is that if you use the embedding, Scribus will include "as is" in the PDF, without first asking Ghostscript to convert it to bitmap. No magic involved :-)